# Use temporal class weights in many-to-one RNNs in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a model that uses several many-to-many RNN layers, followed by a single many-to-one layer and a one-to-one decoding layer.

So the first RNN layer uses the parameter "return_sequences=True" and the second RNN layer uses "return_sequences=False".

So far this works, but it falls apart when I add sample weights. If I had a regular many-to-many network, I would simply set sample_weight_mode="temporal" in the compile() function and define the weights as a 2d matrix.

However in my many-to-one case, this doesn't work, as I get the error that temporal weights expect a time dimension in the output. I realize that this is likely due to the fact that my decoding layer is not temporal anymore (many-to-one). But I can't run the network using non-temporal weights as this would not work together with the many-to-many layers.

Is there a solution to having sample weights with mixed many-to-many and many-to-one layers?

Here's my model to hopefully clarify a bit:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
the_input (InputLayer)       (None, 20, 249)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
masking_1 (Masking)          (None, 20, 249)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 20, 64)            16000     
_________________________________________________________________
relu (Activation)            (None, 20, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
simple_rnn_1 (SimpleRNN)     (None, 20, 16)            1296      
_________________________________________________________________
simple_rnn_2 (SimpleRNN)     (None, 16)                528       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 36)                612       
_________________________________________________________________
softmax (Activation)         (None, 36)                0         
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - Just set you `sample_weight_mode` to `None`

> But I can't run the network using non-temporal weights as this would not work together with the many-to-many layers.

This sentence makes me think you don't actually understand what sample weighting should be doing. 
From [keras' docs](https://keras.io/models/model/):

> sample_weight: Optional Numpy array of weights for the training samples, used for weighting the loss function

This means your sample weights will only be used on the loss function (and, on more recent versions, on the weighted metrics also). Since your loss function is a function of your output alone, I see no reason why your time dependent intermediate layers would affect anything at all.

If you have a single output per time sequence, then your sample is the entire time sequence, not each time step. Thus making your sample weights no different then the ones you would be using for a MLP, for example

Comment: You are right of course, that was a mistake on my part. For some reason I was under the impression that the weights are applied at each layer of the network. But obviously this is only relevant for computing a weighted error which is then backpropagated through the network.